# SQL - Split Row into multiple based on month

Tags: sql-server

> I have data in a row as below in SQL (2012) table
>
> `ID     Value   StartDate   EndDate
>    123    5000     14/04/2017 15/12/2017`
>
> I would like to Split the row into each individual month as below:

`ID  Value      StartDate  EndDate
123 5000     14/04/2017 30/04/2017
123 5000     01/05/2017 31/05/2017
123 5000     01/06/2017 30/06/2017
123 5000     01/07/2017 31/07/2017
123 5000     01/08/2017 30/08/2017
123 5000     01/09/2017 31/09/2017
123 5000     01/10/2017 31/10/2017
123 5000     01/11/2017 30/11/2017
123 5000     01/12/2017 15/12/2017`

> Appreciate help in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
WITH tally
AS (SELECT TOP (1000)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.object_id) AS N
    FROM master.sys.all_columns t1
        CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns t2),
     rowset
AS (SELECT ID,
           Value,
           DATEADD(m, N - 1, StartDate) AS StartDate,
           Enddate,
           N
    FROM tally, MyDates
    WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(m, N - 1, StartDate)), 
    MONTH(DATEADD(m, N - 1, StartDate)), 1) <= EndDate) 
SELECT Id,
       Value,
       CASE
           WHEN N = 1 THEN
               StartDate
           ELSE
               DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(StartDate), MONTH(StartDate), 1)
       END AS StartDate,
       CASE
           WHEN DATEADD(d, -DAY(DATEADD(m, 1, StartDate)), DATEADD(m, 1, StartDate)) <= EndDate THEN
               DATEADD(d, -DAY(DATEADD(m, 1, StartDate)), DATEADD(m, 1, StartDate))
           ELSE
               Enddate
       END AS EndDate
FROM rowset
ORDER BY ID, StartDate;
```

Comment: Hi Cetin, Many thanks for your time and quick response. your seems to have worked except that the last  two months are not splitting. Like here  in one the examples i have using your script. this is the last line `9674  649.0 2018-02-01 2018-03-01 ` ideally I would expect this line to futher split into two one till 2018-02-28 and finally another one till 2018-03-01. Hope this make sense. Can you please look into this for me.APPRICIATE YOUR HELP

Comment: @staq, you are right. Edited the code. You already marked the other reply as answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
Use below query to get the result

DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    ID INT
    ,Value NUMERIC(10,2)
    ,StartDate DATE
    ,EndDate DATE
)

DECLARE @NewTable TABLE
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,item INT
    ,Value NUMERIC(10,2)
    ,StartDate DATE
    ,EndDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT 123,5000    ,'2017-04-14','2018-12-15'

DECLARE @SDate date
DECLARE @EDate date
declare @LastDay INT =0

 SELECT top 1 @SDate=StartDate,@EDate=EndDate  FROM @Temp     


 declare @Year int = 0
 declare @Month int = 0


declare @Index INT =1
DECLARE @Lenght int =DATEDIFF(MONTH,@SDate,@EDate) +1



WHILE @Index<=@Lenght
BEGIN

    IF @Index=1 BEGIN
       -- first record
       SELECT @Year= YEAR(@SDate)
       SELECT @Month = MONTH(@SDate)
       -- get last day of the date
       SELECT @LastDay = day(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@SDate)+1,0)))       
       SELECT @EDate= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Year)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Month)+'- 
 '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@LastDay)        
    INSERT INTO @NewTable
    SELECT 123,5000,@SDate, @EDate
  END ELSE IF @Index = @Lenght BEGIN
    SELECT @Month = @Month+1
    IF @Month>12 BEGIN
        SELECT @Month =1
        SELECT @Year =@Year +1
    END ELSE BEGIN
        SELECT @Year= YEAR(@EDate)
    END
    SELECT @SDate =CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Year)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Month)+ '-01'
    INSERT INTO @NewTable
    SELECT 123,5000    ,@SDate,@EDate
END ELSE BEGIN

    SELECT @Month = @Month+1
    if @Month>12 BEGIN
        SELECT @Month =1
        SELECT @Year =@Year +1
    END


    SELECT @SDate =CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Year)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Month)+ '-01'

    SELECT @LastDay = day(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@SDate)+1,0)))
    SELECT @EDate= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Year)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Month)+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@LastDay) 

    INSERT INTO @NewTable
    SELECT 123,5000    ,@SDate,@EDate


END


SELECT @Index=@Index+1
```

end

SELECT * from @NewTable

--select day(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,getdate())+1,0)))

Comment: Isn't that an overkill when there are simpler ways? Also, have you ever read carefully what he needs as an output? And also, what would happen if the source had more than one row?

Comment: And BTW creating a date value like that is calling for errors. Do not use dashes if you have to create from a string but pad with zero(s).

Comment: Yes Cetin, you are right, your query is far better than me and than you for your advice, I will take care in future post.

Comment: Many thanks Ankur for your time,  after running your code i have found that for `21 123 5000.00 2018-12-01 2018-11-30`  instead of end date 2018-12-15.

Comment: If i were to implement your script, how should i go about doing this for my whole dataset. Say my table name ##temp with thousands of lines of data. Appriciate your response.

Comment: You can use cursor and process the data one by one